# UiLifecycleHelper cannot be resolved to a type in facebook

Tags: android, facebook-android-sdk

I have a problem in loading UiLifecycleHelper class from facebook package in android. I have searched alot and didnot find the solution,but In stackoverflow I found the same question but didnot find the solution for that. Can any one help me? thanks in advance

Comment: what is the problem ? any error log or stacktrace would help

Comment: Still I didnot run the application while writing that class it is showing error I try to import with ctrl+shift+O but it doesn't work. I added facebook sdk to project also\

Comment: from where you downloaded the library

Comment: http://javatechig.com/android/using-facebook-sdk-in-android-example from here

Comment: # Murtaza Khursheed Hussain ru there do u have any solution for this?

Comment: which sdk version you are using ?

Comment: Download new lib from https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/downloads

Answer (score 0):

I think Facebook dependencies no longer support "**UiLifecycleHelper**" to upgraded version. When I use **Dependencies of facebook as 4.+**, it is not work. And then I replace it 3.19.1 - it works for me.